# Need Guidance on Nested If Function

Tags: excel, vba

If possible, I would like to see if I can consolidate these 4 functions into one.  If the first condition is not met, I'd like the entire process to stop.  Hopefully this is enough information.  Thank you in advance.

```
For Each c In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
If c = "Round 1 Bid" Then
c.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
Exit For
End If
Next                  

For Each b In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
If b = "" Then
b.Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
Exit For
End If
Next   

For Each c In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
If c = "Round 1 Bid" Then
c.Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = " Round 1 Bid"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
Exit For
End If
Next    

For Each b In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
If b = "" Then
b.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
Exit For
End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what you're trying to do?

Comment: A screenshot of your before and expected after would also be beneficial

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to stop in all the For's or just the first one so I put it in all, remove the others if you don't need them.

Just put an else in there with End:

```
For Each c In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
    If c = "Round 1 Bid" Then
        c.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Exit For
    Else
        End
    End If
Next                  

For Each b In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
    If b = "" Then
        b.PasteSpecial 'what are you pasting just values? if so use xlpastevalues if everything then use xlpasteall after PasteSpecial
        Exit For
    Else
        End
    End If
Next   

For Each c In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
    If c = "Round 1 Bid" Then
        With c
            .Formula2R1C1 = " Round 1 Bid"
            Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Copy
        End With
        Exit For
    Else
        End
    End If
Next    

For Each b In Range("A2:CA2").Cells
    If b = "" Then
        b.Offset(1, -1).PasteSpecial 'what are you pasting just values? if so use xlpastevalues if everything then use xlpasteall after PasteSpecial
        Exit For
    Else
        End
    End If
Next
```

Also don't select things, I have updated your code to remove the selects.